# How to install a .ipa file into my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I need to install an app into my iPhone, I have the .ipa file of that app and also my device is added to the developer's account. 
I downloaded the file and open it in iTunes and when I am trying to sync my iPhone with iTunes it gives me an error saying "WBW app was not installed on your iPhone".
Could anyone can please provide me with the steps or any link?

Comment: Creating an ipa and testing before submitting builds is not related to programming? That's how I searched to wind up here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to install the provisioning profile (drag and drop it into iTunes).  Then drag and drop the .ipa.  Ensure you device is set to sync apps, and try again.

Comment: Further comments: the provisioning profile will have the file extension .mobileprovision, and the only instance in which you wouldn't need one would be if you'd received an enterprise build.

Comment: Do you need to have a Developer account or something to get this to work? Mine is not working...

Comment: You can also email the .mobileprovision file to the phone and run it directly from the mail app. You can then install the app using the "iPhone Configuration Utility" (Google it). This has the advantage that you can install the .ipa file if you don't currently have access to the computer the iPhone is synced to or if the iTunes method isn't working.

Comment: or just add it to itunes and just grad it on your device on the sidebar

Comment: Drag and drop doesn't work in latest (11.0) iTunes. At least not on Windows 7. You have to add the provisioning profile and .ipa files by using menu option "Add to library" (or CTRL+O shortcut).

Comment: Nux's comment should really be the accepted answer. Dragging and dropping now longer works on the latest version of itunes